# Reverse changes when value is no longer selected (specified IDs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a function that changes the color of a text of one of 12 DIVs on my website.

```
$('.position_select').change(function(){ 
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var shelf = $("#mockup_shelf_" + selected)
  $(shelf).css({ color: "#FF6633" });
}).change();
```

It's a mock-up for a user to show on which position they've chosen to display their buttons. It's based on which of the numbers (from 1 to 12) are selected in select tag:

```
f.select :position, (1..12), {prompt: 'Select Position'}, {required: 'true', class: "position_select" }
```

I want to change this DIV's text back to black (or all unselected DIVs) if the user unselects this specific position and chooses another. How can I do it? 
Colors get back to what they should be on page reload, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just update all elements to the default color, and then change the color of the element that corresponds to the selected item like this:

```
$('.position_select').change(function(){ 
  //reset all elements color
  $("[id^=mockup_shelf_]").css({ color: "#000000" });

  //now find and set the color of the selected item
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var shelf = $("#mockup_shelf_" + selected)
  $(shelf).css({ color: "#FF6633" });
}).change();
```

I'm using the `starts with` attribute selector since the beginning of every ID is the same.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

> The [attribute^=value] selector matches every element whose attribute
>   value begins with a specified value.

---

Alternately, you could assign the same class to all `mockup_shelf` elements and then use this class selector to target them all: `$(".mockup_shelf").css({ color: "#000000" });`

---

And since good things come in threes, you could also completely eliminate any styling information from the script and create 2 css classes in your stylesheet (allowing you to do more complex styling easier). For example:

```
.mockup_shelf {
    color: #000000;
}
.mockup_shelf.selected {
    color: #FF6633;
}
```

All of your `mockup_shelf` elements would have the `mockup_shelf` class, and then in script you could add or remove the `selected` class like so:

```
$('.position_select').change(function(){ 
  //reset selected element's color
  $(".mockup_shelf.selected").removeClass("selected");

  //now find and set the color of the selected item
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var shelf = $("#mockup_shelf_" + selected)
  $(shelf).addClass("selected");
}).change();
```

**EDIT**
Since you clarified that you have a multi-select box, I've gone ahead and created a sample fiddle showing how to accomplish this with multiple selections:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofhw085r/

```
  $('.position_select').change(function() {
    //remove class from all shelves to reset them
    $(".mockup_shelf.selected").removeClass("selected");

    var $position_select = $(this); //explicitly labeling this to avoid confusion in the next part
    $position_select.find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var $option = $(this); //'this' now has a new context, so label it to avoid confusing it with 'this' in the outer context
      var shelf = $("#mockup_shelf_" + $option.val());
      shelf.addClass("selected");
    });
  }).change();
```

Essentially, every time the change event fires on your `select`, you'll reset the styles on all `mockup_shelf` elements and then loop through every `selected` option (using jquery's built-in `:selected` selector), and then add the `selected` class to the associated shelf.

Comment: I might make shorten the last three lines of that handler to one or two using `$("#mockup_shelf_" + $(this).val()).addClass("selected");`.  Great answer though, really like the approach you suggest at the end.

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggested improvements, they are great indeed. The problem with this solution is that I want to display not only one but all selected positions in color and black out the rest of the DIVs.

Comment: @JoeyEkwatrepedrey you can use the exact same technique. You would just set the selected color for all positions selected.

Comment: @JoeyEkwatrepedrey I've updated the answer to show how you can do this same thing with multiple selections

Comment: @Joel Nonetheless, I'm afraid I don't know how to get all those selected DIVs. If I wasn't clear - user can set up to 12 identical selection tags inside this form , all with the same class ".position_select" and I want to catch all those selected values. It's still impossible to color more than one at a time.